# Выскакивает ошибка при повторной сортировке

Tags: c, сортировка

Вывести список на экран, упорядочив по номеру
устройства, а внутри каждого номера устройства по
времени получения.

номер устройства отправителя (целое положительное четырехзначное число);
текст сообщения (строка 50 символов);
время получения (в формате ЧЧ:ММ:СС).

При компиляции выскакивает ошибка: incompatible type for argument 2( или 1 ) of ‘strncmp’

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>



 int main()
{
//Создание структуры MESSAGE
typedef struct{
    char text[50];
    char number[4];
    double date;
    unsigned count;
}MESSAGE;

//Ввод кол-ва сообщений и направления сортировки
int N = 0, sort = 0;
printf("Insert count of your messages: ");
scanf("%d", &N);
printf("Choose sort messages name (1 - up, 0 - down): ");
scanf("%d", &sort);

//Ввод сообщений
MESSAGE message[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    printf("%d message text: ", i+1);
    scanf("%s", &message[i].text);
    printf("%d message system number: ", i+1);
    scanf("%s", &message[i].number);
    printf("%d message date: ", i+1);
    scanf("%lf", &message[i].date);
    printf("%d messages count: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &message[i].count);
}

//Сортировка сообщений по устройству
MESSAGE temp;
for(int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < N; j++){
        if(strcmp(message[i].number, message[j].number) == 0){
            temp = message[i+1];
            message[i+1] = message[j];
            message[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

//Сортировка сообщений по времени
for(int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < N; j++){
        if(sort == 0){
            if (strncmp(message[i].date, message[j].date, 1) > 0 && strcmp(message[i].number, 
message[j].number) == 0){
                temp = message[i];
                message[i] = message[j];
                message[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        else if(sort == 1){
            if (strncmp(message[i].date, message[j].date, 1) < 0 && strcmp(message[i].number, 
message[j].number) == 0){
                temp = message[i];
                message[i] = message[j];
                message[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Вывод сообщений
printf("\v\tMESSAGE LIST:\n\n");
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    printf("\nMESSAGE %d\n", i + 1);
    printf("%d message text: ", i+1);
    printf("%s\n", message[i].text);
    printf("%d message system number: ", i+1);
    printf("%s\n", message[i].number);
    printf("%d message date: ", i+1);
    printf("%lf\n", message[i].date);
    printf("%d messages count: ", i+1);
    printf("%d\n", message[i].count);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `data` - это ж `double`. Зачем Вы передаете число в функцию, которая ожидает строку. Числа можно просто сравнивать

Comment: Блин, а есть короткий алгоритм для сравнивания вводимых чисел?

Comment: По Вашему ТЗ ничего не понятно. Что значит " внутри каждого номера устройства по времени получения."?

Comment: Сначала мы сортируем сообщения по номеру устройства, потом по времени. Например от устройства 1111 пришло два сообщения, а от 2222  ровно одно От первого устройства первое сообщение пришло ровно в 15 часов другое в  16 часов, сл-но если сортировать по возрастанию, смс от 15 часов будет первое. А от устройства 2222 пришло 1 сообщение, сл-но там и сортировать не нужно.